# How do I prove by contradiction that Art's taller than Bob?

Tags: logic

From: Philip Johnson-Laird [BA PhD Psychology (UCL)](https://dof.princeton.edu/about/clerk-faculty/emeritus/philip-nicholas-johnson-laird), Stuart Professor of Psychology Emeritus at Princeton.    (Author isn't  a logician.)    [*How We Reason*  (1st edn 2008)](https://www.amazon.ca/How-We-Reason-Philip-Johnson-Laird/dp/0199551332). [p. 274](https://books.google.com/books?id=UjYsJN0krNYC&pg=PA274&lpg=PA274&dq=%22art+is+taller+than+cal+to+a+greater+extent%22&source=bl&ots=JcZfDF6axP&sig=aWuqdUXiAEzegRhSn0gTSRZpdf4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyzI3-xJPcAhWEw4MKHXh1AjwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22art%20is%20taller%20than%20cal%20to%20a%20greater%20extent%22&f=false).

> Experiments have therefore posed relational problems of this sort:
>
> > **[1.]** Art is taller than Cal to a greater extent than Bob is taller than Dan.
> >     **[2.]** Bob is taller than Dan to a greater extent than Cal is taller than Dan.
>
> What is the order of the four individuals in terms of their height?
>   The answer in this case, with the tallest first, is: Art, Bob, Cal, Dan. One strategy
>   for solving the problem is to realize that the second premise establishes the
>   order:
>
> > **[3.]** Bob Cal Dan
>
> and then to use the first premise to add Art in his appropriate place. If you
>   doubt whether Art is taller than Bob, you should work out the consequences
>   of the supposition that they’re the same height. It is then impossible for the
>   first premise to be true, because
>   **[4.] *Bob* would also have to be taller than Cal to
>   a greater extent than Bob is taller than Dan**, and that would conflict with the
>   order of the three of them above.

I understand that the author is proving  by contradiction that A's height > B's.

5. Doesn't 3 imply, and thus, substantiate 4?
6. If yes to 5, how does 4 beget the contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement translated into an inequality is
 $$ A-C > B-D > 0. \tag{1}$$ The second statement translates into an inequality
 $$  B-D > C-D > 0. \tag{2}$$ 
The first inequality implies, using algebra, that
 $$  A-B > C-D. \tag{3} $$
The second inequality implies, using algebra, that
 $$ B-C > 0. \tag{4} $$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ together gives
 $$ A-B > C-D > 0. \tag{5} $$
Finally, $(4)$ and $(5)$ together implies
 $$ A > B > C > D. \tag{6} $$
 There is no need for proof by contradiction here.

Comment: Thanks. How did you deduce $B−C>C−D$ in your second-last inequality? Can you please edit your answer to explain?

Comment: Thanks again. How do $(4)$ and $(5)$ together imply 
 $(6)$? Can you please edit your answer to explain?